# $K(x)$ not stable relative to $K(x,y)$ and $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Prove that in the extension of an infinite field $K$ by $K(x,y)$, the intermediate field $K(x)$ is Galois over K, but not stable (relative to $K(x, y)$ and $K$).

I know that if K(x) is algebraic it is stable, but I'm not clear on how to show its unstable when it's not algebraic.

Comment: What does it mean when an extension field is said to be *stable* (relative to some other pair of fields)? Can you give a definition? D_S made one guess. That would have been my first guess, too, but I suspect that is not right, because that property does not hold for all algebraic extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Stable means that $\sigma K(x) \subseteq K(x)$ for any $\sigma \in \textrm{Aut} (K(x,y)/K)$, right?  Well, what about the automorphism $\sigma$ which sends $x$ to $y$?

Comment: *Swaps* $x$ and $y$ might be better...