# Galois theory: infinite field case

Tags: galois-theory

This is an exercise problem from Hungerford Chapter 5.

> Let $K$ be an infinite field. Prove that the intermediate field $K(x)$ of the extension $K\leq K(x,y)$ is Galois over $K$, but is not stable relative to $K(x,y)$ and $K$.

Here stable means: if $E$ is an intermediate field of the extension $K\subset F$, $E$ is said to be stable (relative to $K$ and $F$) if every $K$-automorphism $\sigma\in Aut_KF$ maps $E$ into itself.

This question was already asked here:[$K(x)$ not stable relative to $K(x,y)$ and $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642317/kx-not-stable-relative-to-kx-y-and-k), but the problem remains unanswered. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't though about this in a while.  What does $\sigma: x \leftrightarrow y$, i.e., the map which exchanges $x$ and $y$, do?

Comment: @EricTowers Can you explain little bit more when $x$ and $y$ are interchanged? Thanks.

Comment: Is it given that $x$ and $y$ are transcendental elements, algebraically independent over $K$?

Answer (score 2):

We need $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}_K K(x,y)$.  To specify a $\sigma$ it suffices to specify the images of $1$, $x$, and $y$.  Try
$$  \sigma : \begin{Bmatrix} 1 \mapsto 1  \\ x \mapsto y \\ y \mapsto x \end{Bmatrix}  \text{.}  $$
(Of course, we already know $$(K(x))(y) = K(x,y) \cong K(y,x) = (K(y))(x)  \text{,}  $$
so there should be o surprises showing this $\sigma$ is an automorphism fixing $K$ pointwise.)
$K(x)$ is not mapped into $K(x)$.  In fact, $\sigma(K(x)) \cap K(x) = K$ but $\sigma(x) = y  \not \in K(x)$.